# images quality in html

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I have a website with images. The code for the images is like this:

```
<img class="featurette-image2 img-fluid mx-auto" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="500x500"
    src="/images/stuck.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
```

and it looks like this:

The quality is increased. I know that the width and height is set to 500px. Is there any possibilities that the quality is still good?

[image: picture]

Comment: If the source image is smaller than the dimensions you specify, the image will be stretched and quality will not be as good.  It's a bit unclear what you are asking about though ....

Comment: Actually this is my problem: I don't want that the images is stretched. The source images is actually bigger.

Comment: @Behar I can't see any image.

Comment: @DogukanCavus ?

Comment: where is your image? please provide a working snippet.

Comment: actually I can see the image I uploaded

Comment: Your trying to show a image that only you have on your pc... if we try your code to help you out, we can't see the image. Is that what he meant

Comment: can you help me out how to provide you the image? Sry I am a new to Stack

Comment: @MiguelCruz yes dude.

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful code to css:

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for it:

```html
<img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/ikmedia/backlit.jpg" 
     style="object-fit:scale-down;
            width:200px;
            height:300px;
            border: solid 1px #CCC"
/>
```

`scale-down`:
The content is sized as if none or contain were specified, whichever would result in a smaller concrete object size.